# Pushbutton Ground Selection

Tags: power, ground

I need some ideas for a pushbutton ground selection circuit.

I want to be able to switch grounds using momentary pushbuttons. I could do this simply with a rotary switch, but due to design I'm trying to avoid this. The pushbuttons should deselect the previously selected ground. I have a simplified drawing using LEDs to illustrate the idea.

[image: ground selection circuit]

This is to show the circuit with a rotary switch (trying to avoid this setup).
[image]

Comment: Please tell us the concrete behavior of the circuit, which you desire.  For example.  Do all of the LEDs light up together?  Are the buttons momentary or latching?  What is this LED arrangement for?  Why do you need a selector circuit, as opposed to fixed wiring?  I know that you're trying to avout the rotary switch, but if you could have one, what would that circuit look like?

Comment: This is essentially like push button AV select boxes, where pressing the button for input A would deselect input B. If only I knew what that type of button is called.

Comment: @Passerby Yes this is exactly what i'm trying to do to. Similar to AV select boxes, except I'm just changing ground. Pressing button A turns on and latches LED A. All other LEDs are turned off. Then pressing button B turns on and latches LED B and turns off all other LEDs. The pushbuttons will latch although the mechanical button itself is a momentary button.

Comment: I expected the switches @Passerby mentioned to be a piece of cake to track down, but it looks like they're largely obsolete and the only place I could find them was a surplus shop and not in the configuration you need anyway. Personally I'd take a look at using a small microcontroller, although that's a bit of hassle if you don't already have a programmer and a bit of experience. Is it actually LEDs you're driving or something that needs a decent ground like an audio signal?

Comment: @PeterJ I'm going to need a decent ground. The LEDs serve as a continuity check. I left out the rest of the schematic for simplicity. There will be 24v going thru the line.

Comment: @Johnny Holguin You mean 24V for the LED? Because looking at the circuit, I would rather suggest you use a microcontroller, just as suggested above. Except that the circuit you have provided is just for an illustration. An idea/view of the real application could help give a good suggestion.

Comment: If you need to switch ground with a momentary switch, a microcontroller with some transistors will work nicely. The switches on the inputs to the mcu, and the transistors on the outputs. a single 8 or 14 pin mcu with minimal coding (like 20 lines of code) will work.

Comment: This isn't "changing ground" but simply turning on one of four devices exclusively. The question title should be, "I am looking for a single pole, quadruple throw switch".

Comment: I too remember seeing those interlinked pushbuttons in parts catalogs, and as channel select on old car radios, and I too can't find them or even reliably work out what they're called.

Comment: @pjc50 I think "interlocked" is a common term for them.

Answer (score 1):

I would have used a microcontroller with some transistors and a short code, but if you want to use logic, maybe you could go for a [JK Flip-Flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#JK_flip-flop) with transistors on their output.

Each button can set a pulse to both J and K on a single flip-flop, and also send a pulse to the K-input on all others. This way, when you press one button, the output of its respective flip-flop will toggle its output and change the transistor state, hence turning on/off the LED. At the same time it sends a reset to all others and turning their output (transistors) off. I am not very used to using latches, I prefer a microcontroller, so please correct me if I am wrong on this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD9B9Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the parts, with the aid of a Passerby:

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/98138.pdf

http://www.electronicsurplus.com/Item/2115/Schadow%20-%20Switch_%20pushbutton_%20switchbank_%20DPDT%20%28%20x%204%20%29_%20-%203-536/

They're either "interlocking" switches or "switchbank" parts. Both of which are a bit of a pain to search for. They don't seem too widely available, presumably they are dying out as car radios replace mechanical switches with digital presets.